# node doesn't send kinect data over network

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-kinect, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run an openni node on one machine (Ubuntu 11.04) and publich the data to the master node, which is on another machine (also Ubuntu 11.04) to view it in rviz there. I believe to have my network set up correctly, as I can ping from one machine to the other, and "rostopic list" on the master node returns the topics published by the openni node on the other machine. My problem is that there is no data coming through - "rostopic echo ..." returns nothing on the master node, and rviz therefore obviously doesn't receive anything either. On the machine running openni (the one supposed to be sending the data) I can view the kinect data just fine. When I check my network traffic with system tools, I see that no data is being sent at all. I also have all firewalls disabled.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10954/node-doesn%27t-send-kinect-data-over-network/) by [pdowling](https://answers.ros.org/users/971/pdowling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-19**:
Related: http://answers.ros.org/question/1881/turtlebot-unable-to-contact-my-own-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that you can ping the hostname of each machine in both directions.

e.g. when your master is pc1 and the other machine is lap1, you need to be able to ping pc1 from lap1 and lap1 from pc1.

It needs to work in both directions and it needs to be able to ping the hostnames not just the ips. If that isn't the case you can set the [ROS_IP](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME) environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1